# Get Model's Parameters in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a generator in rails but I'm getting stuck at trying to access an existing model's parameters. Basically I want to do something like this:

```
# user is a model the has the parameters "id: integer, name: string, and email: string"
User.parameters.each do |parameter|
   # do something with id, name, email
   parameter.key
   # do something with integer, string, string
   parameter.value
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is this

```
User.columns_hash.each do |key, value|
 key
 value.type
end
```

`value.type` will give you the type as a symbol. You can convert it to a string if you want it as a string

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for attributes, rather than parameters.

```
user = User.first
user.attributes.each do |key, value|
  # do something here with keys and values
  puts key if key
  puts value if value
end
```

Notice I'm grabbing an actual instance of the model as well as checking for nils (the if key/ if value part)

Comment: you may be right. any ideas how i could use them in the fashion i described above? I need to access them as strings

Comment: Rob, I've added some sample code to provide further clarification.

Comment: no I need to actually use the class name, I can't do User.first in the context I'm using it. User.attributes gives me NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes' for #<Class:0x007f9200383418>

Comment: doing User.new almost gets me what I need, but it returns "id, nil, name, nil, email, nil". I need to get "id, integer, name, string, email, string"

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Need to use columns_hash like this:

```
Event.columns_hash.each {|k,v| puts "#{k} => #{v.type}"}
```

Credit to [Getting types of the attributes in an ActiveRecord object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2399556/getting-types-of-the-attributes-in-an-activerecord-object)